# selective form fields using django(1.3) forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm using django forms in my django1.3 application.

Here is the snippet from `forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('name', 'address', 
                  'city', 'state', 
                  'country', 'telephone',)
```

In the views.py I am using [django profiles](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles) and passing the `AccountForm` like this,

```
from profiles.views import profile_detail, edit_profile
def profile_update(request):
    # some code here
    # some more code here
    # to set extra_context
    return edit_profile(request, extra_context=extra_context, 
                        form_class=AccountForm,
                        success_url='/some/success/url/here')
```

The html file renders it as follows,

```
{% for field in form %}
  <label>{{field.label|safe }}</label>
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am looking for a way to selective include fields in the form on some condition, like based on the value of the field in the `Account` model.

Example if `Account.joining_date > datetime.date(1,3,2010)` only then  include field `telephone` in the form, else do not. How do I achieve this functionality? I'd be glad to provide any extra info if required to get a solution to this :)

Thanks in advance!